# Can this recursive function be turned into an iterative function with similar performance?

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, numba

I am writing a function in python using numba to label objects in a 2D or 3D array, meaning all orthogonally connected cells with the same value in the input array will be given a unique label from 1 to N in the output array, where N is the number of orthogonally connected groups. It is very similar to functions such as [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html#scipy.ndimage.label) and similar functions in libraries such as scikit-image, but those functions label all orthogonally connected non-zero groups of cells, so it would merge connected groups with different values, which I don't want. For example, given this input:

```
[0 0 7 7 0 0
 0 0 7 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 7
 0 6 6 0 0 7
 0 0 4 4 0 0]
```

The scipy function would return

```
[0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 3
 0 2 2 0 0 3
 0 0 2 2 0 0]
```

Notice that the 6s and 4s were merged into the label `2`. I want them to be labeled as separate groups, e.g.:

```
[0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 4
 0 2 2 0 0 4
 0 0 3 3 0 0]
```

I [asked this about a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72974571/find-groups-of-adjacent-cells-in-a-numpy-ndarray-with-the-same-value) and have been using the solution in the accepted answer, however I am working on optimizing the runtime of my code and am revisiting this problem.

For the data size I generally work with, the linked solution takes about 1m30s to run. I wrote the following recursive algorithm which takes about 30s running as regular python and with numba's JIT runs in 1-2s (side note, I hate that adjacent function, any tips to make it less messy while still numba-compatible would be appreciated):

```
@numba.njit
def adjacent(idx, shape):
    coords = []
    if len(shape) > 2:
        if idx[0] < shape[0] - 1:
            coords.append((idx[0] + 1, idx[1], idx[2]))
        if idx[0] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0] - 1, idx[1], idx[2]))
        if idx[1] < shape[1] - 1:
            coords.append((idx[0], idx[1] + 1, idx[2]))
        if idx[1] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0], idx[1] - 1, idx[2]))
        if idx[2] < shape[2] - 1:
            coords.append((idx[0], idx[1], idx[2] + 1))
        if idx[2] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0], idx[1], idx[2] - 1))
    else:
        if idx[0] < shape[0] - 1:
            coords.append((idx[0] + 1, idx[1]))
        if idx[0] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0] - 1, idx[1]))
        if idx[1] < shape[1] - 1:
            coords.append((idx[0], idx[1] + 1))
        if idx[1] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0], idx[1] - 1))
    return coords


@numba.njit
def apply_label(labels, decoded_image, current_label, idx):
    labels[idx] = current_label
    for aidx in adjacent(idx, labels.shape):
        if decoded_image[aidx] == decoded_image[idx] and labels[aidx] == 0:
            apply_label(labels, decoded_image, current_label, aidx)


@numba.njit
def label_image(decoded_image):
    labels = np.zeros_like(decoded_image, dtype=np.uint32)
    current_label = 0
    for idx in zip(*np.where(decoded_image >= 0)):
        if labels[idx] == 0:
            current_label += 1
            apply_label(labels, decoded_image, current_label, idx)
    return labels, current_label
```

This worked for some data, but crashed on other data and I found the issue is that when there are very large objects to label, the recursion limit is reached. I tried to rewrite `label_image` to not use recursion, but it now takes ~10s with numba. Still a huge improvement from where I started, but it seems like it should be possible to get the same performance as the recursive version. Here is my iterative version:

```
@numba.njit
def label_image(decoded_image):
    labels = np.zeros_like(decoded_image, dtype=np.uint32)
    current_label = 0
    for idx in zip(*np.where(decoded_image >= 0)):
        if labels[idx] == 0:
            current_label += 1
            idxs = [idx]
            while idxs:
                cidx = idxs.pop()
                if labels[cidx] == 0:
                    labels[cidx] = current_label
                    for aidx in adjacent(cidx, labels.shape):
                        if labels[aidx] == 0 and decoded_image[aidx] == decoded_image[idx]:
                            idxs.append(aidx)
    return labels, current_label
```

Is there a way I can improve this?

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation of the logic used to assign the labels?

Comment: They are assigned sequentially from 1 to N to groups of adjacent values. In the example, the group of 7s gets the label `1`, the group of 6s gets the label `2` and the group of 4s gets the label `3`. The exact assignment doesn't matter, e.g. the labels for the 7s and 6s could be swapped so that the 7s are `2` and the 6s `1`. It just matters that there are 3 separate groups labeled `1`, `2`, and `3`. Also the 4s in the example could be 7s and the output wouldn't change because the two groups of 7s would not be connected and so would still be considered separate groups. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Is it important that the groups be labeled 1-3 in that order or it just matters that there is a group 1, 2, and 3, but it doesn't matter which group is given which number? Also, you provided a 2D input, but am I understanding correctly that you want to be able to apply this to 3D inputs?

Comment: The order doesn't matter, they can be freely swapped. I need to be able to apply it to both 2D and 3D inputs. This is handled in the `adjacent` function where it checks the number of dimensions and returns the adjacent coordinates accordingly.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill . It looks like the *span filling* algorithm as been chosen for the provided answer so far.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I think "span filling" (which a DFS which prioritizes X over Y over Z naturally yields) is probably the best choice cache-locality wise, though I'm not sure how much that matters here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can this recursive function be turned into an iterative function with similar performance?

Turning this into an iterative function is straightforward, considering it's just a simple depth-first search (you could also use a breadth-first search using a queue instead of a stack here, both work). Simply use a stack to keep track of the nodes to visit. Here's a general solution that works with any number of dimensions:

```py
def label_image(decoded_image):
    shape = decoded_image.shape
    labels = np.zeros_like(decoded_image, dtype=np.uint32)
    current_label = 0
    for idx in zip(*np.where(decoded_image > 0)):
        if labels[idx] == 0:
            current_label += 1
            stack = [idx]
            while stack:
                top = stack.pop()
                labels[top] = current_label
                for i in range(0, len(shape)):
                    if top[i] > 0:
                        neighbor = list(top)
                        neighbor[i] -= 1
                        neighbor = tuple(neighbor)
                        if decoded_image[neighbor] == decoded_image[idx] and labels[neighbor] == 0:
                            stack.append(neighbor)
                    if top[i] < shape[i] - 1:
                        neighbor = list(top)
                        neighbor[i] += 1
                        neighbor = tuple(neighbor)
                        if decoded_image[neighbor] == decoded_image[idx] and labels[neighbor] == 0:
                            stack.append(neighbor)
    return labels
```

Adding or subtracting one from the i-th component of the tuple is awkward though (I'm going over a temporary list here) and numba doesn't accept it (type error). One simple solution would be to explicitly write versions for 2d and 3d, which will likely greatly help performance:

```py
@numba.njit
def label_image_2d(decoded_image):
    w, h = decoded_image.shape
    labels = np.zeros_like(decoded_image, dtype=np.uint32)
    current_label = 0
    for idx in zip(*np.where(decoded_image > 0)):
        if labels[idx] == 0:
            current_label += 1
            stack = [idx]
            while stack:
                x, y = stack.pop()
                if decoded_image[x, y] != decoded_image[idx] or labels[x, y] != 0:
                    continue # already visited or not part of this group
                labels[x, y] = current_label
                if x > 0: stack.append((x-1, y))
                if x+1 < w: stack.append((x+1, y))
                if y > 0: stack.append((x, y-1))
                if y+1 < h: stack.append((x, y+1))
    return labels

@numba.njit
def label_image_3d(decoded_image):
    w, h, l = decoded_image.shape
    labels = np.zeros_like(decoded_image, dtype=np.uint32)
    current_label = 0
    for idx in zip(*np.where(decoded_image > 0)):
        if labels[idx] == 0:
            current_label += 1
            stack = [idx]
            while stack:
                x, y, z = stack.pop()
                if decoded_image[x, y, z] != decoded_image[idx] or labels[x, y, z] != 0:
                    continue # already visited or not part of this group
                labels[x, y, z] = current_label
                if x > 0: stack.append((x-1, y, z))
                if x+1 < w: stack.append((x+1, y, z))
                if y > 0: stack.append((x, y-1, z))
                if y+1 < h: stack.append((x, y+1, z))
                if z > 0: stack.append((x, y, z-1))
                if z+1 < l: stack.append((x, y, z+1))
    return labels

def label_image(decoded_image):
    dim = len(decoded_image.shape)
    if dim == 2:
        return label_image_2d(decoded_image)
    assert dim == 3
    return label_image_3d(decoded_image)
```

Note also that the iterative solution doesn't suffer from stack limits: `np.full((100,100,100), 1)` works just fine in the iterative solution, but fails in the recursive solution (segfaults if using numba).

Doing a very rudimentary benchmark of

```py
for i in range(1, 10000):
    label_image(np.full((20,20,20), i))
```

(many iterations to minimize the impact of JIT, could also do a few warmup runs, then start measuring time or similar)

The iterative solution seems to be several times faster (<del>about 5x on my machine</del> see below). You could probably optimize the recursive solution and get it to a comparable speed, f.e. by avoiding the temporary `coords` list or by changing the `np.where` to `> 0`.

I don't know how well numba can optimize the zipped `np.where`. For further optimization, you could consider (and benchmark) using explicit nested `for x in range(0, w): for y in range(0, h):` loops there.

---

To remain competitive with the merge strategy proposed by Nick, I've optimized this further, picking some low hanging fruit:

- Convert the `zip` to explicit loops with `continue` rather than `np.where`.
- Store `decoded_image[idx]` in a local variable (ideally shouldn't matter, but doesn't hurt).
- Reuse the stack. This prevents unnecessary (re)allocations and GC strain. It could further be considered to provide an initial capacity for the stack (of `w*h` or `w*h*l` respectively).

```py
@numba.njit
def label_image_2d(decoded_image):
    w, h = decoded_image.shape
    labels = np.zeros_like(decoded_image, dtype=np.uint32)
    current_label = 0
    stack = []
    for sx in range(0, w):
        for sy in range(0, h):
            start = (sx, sy)
            image_label = decoded_image[start]
            if image_label <= 0 or labels[start] != 0:
                continue
            current_label += 1
            stack.append(start)
            while stack:
                x, y = stack.pop()
                if decoded_image[x, y] != image_label or labels[x, y] != 0:
                    continue # already visited or not part of this group
                labels[x, y] = current_label
                if x > 0: stack.append((x-1, y))
                if x+1 < w: stack.append((x+1, y))
                if y > 0: stack.append((x, y-1))
                if y+1 < h: stack.append((x, y+1))
    return labels

@numba.njit
def label_image_3d(decoded_image):
    w, h, l = decoded_image.shape
    labels = np.zeros_like(decoded_image, dtype=np.uint32)
    current_label = 0
    stack = []
    for sx in range(0, w):
        for sy in range(0, h):
            for sz in range(0, l):
                start = (sx, sy, sz)
                image_label = decoded_image[start]
                if image_label <= 0 or labels[start] != 0:
                    continue
                current_label += 1
                stack.append(start)
                while stack:
                    x, y, z = stack.pop()
                    if decoded_image[x, y, z] != image_label or labels[x, y, z] != 0:
                        continue # already visited or not part of this group
                    labels[x, y, z] = current_label
                    if x > 0: stack.append((x-1, y, z))
                    if x+1 < w: stack.append((x+1, y, z))
                    if y > 0: stack.append((x, y-1, z))
                    if y+1 < h: stack.append((x, y+1, z))
                    if z > 0: stack.append((x, y, z-1))
                    if z+1 < l: stack.append((x, y, z+1))
    return labels
```

I then cobbled together a benchmark to compare the four approaches (original recursive, old iterative, new iterative, merge-based), putting them in four different modules:

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit

import rec
import iter_old
import iter_new
import merge

shape = (100, 100, 100)
n = 20
for module in [rec, iter_old, iter_new, merge]:
    print(module)

    label_image = module.label_image
    # Trigger compilation of 2d & 3d functions
    label_image(np.zeros((1, 1)))
    label_image(np.zeros((1, 1, 1)))

    i = 0
    def test_full():
        global i
        i += 1
        label_image(np.full(shape, i))
    print("single group:", timeit.timeit(test_full, number=n))
    print("random (few groups):", timeit.timeit(
        lambda: label_image(np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 10, size = shape)),
        number=n))
    print("random (many groups):", timeit.timeit(
        lambda: label_image(np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 400, size = shape)),
        number=n))
    print("only groups:", timeit.timeit(
        lambda: label_image(np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)),
        number=n))
```

This outputs something like

```
<module 'rec' from '...'>
single group: 32.39212468900041
random (few groups): 14.648884047001047
random (many groups): 13.304533919001187
only groups: 13.513677138000276
<module 'iter_old' from '...'>
single group: 10.287227957000141
random (few groups): 17.37535468200076
random (many groups): 14.506630064999626
only groups: 13.132202609998785
<module 'iter_new' from '...'>
single group: 7.388022166000155
random (few groups): 11.585243002000425
random (many groups): 9.560101995000878
only groups: 8.693653742000606
<module 'merge' from '...'>
single group: 14.657021331999204
random (few groups): 14.146574055999736
random (many groups): 13.412314713001251
only groups: 12.642367746000673
```

It seems to me that the improved iterative approach may be better. Note that the original rudimentary benchmark seems to be the worst case for the recursive variant. In general the difference isn't as large.

The tested array is pretty small (20³). If I test with a larger array (100³), and a smaller n (20), I get roughly the following results (`rec` is omitted because due to stack limits, it would segfault):

```
<module 'iter_old' from '...'>
single group: 3.5357716739999887
random (few groups): 4.931695729999774
random (many groups): 3.4671142009992764
only groups: 3.3023930709987326
<module 'iter_new' from '...'>
single group: 2.45903080700009
random (few groups): 2.907660342001691
random (many groups): 2.309699692999857
only groups: 2.052835552000033
<module 'merge' from '...'>
single group: 3.7620838259990705
random (few groups): 3.3524249689999124
random (many groups): 3.126650959999097
only groups: 2.9456547739991947
```

The iterative approach still seems to be more efficient.

Comment: Good. Note that `labels[x, y, z] != 0` can be precomputed in a booleans array (fast since it can be vectorized) so to improve the later memory access (since the resulting boolean array will likely be in cache). This optimization only worth it for large arrays (especially with vertical areas to be labelled). Also note that the function is compiled once so one call is enough for the JIT to warm up. Eager compilation be used to avoid that by providing its signature. Besides, storing unsigned integers in the stack should improve performance since Numba can remove wraparound checks in this case.

Comment: Thank you for all the work you've put into this answer! I have now benchmarked the algorithms on real data and my results are quite different. The merge method from the other answer is ~15x slower than my original recursive method. Your original iterative method is about 5% faster than recursive, and the newer optimized method is about 25% faster. I guess the difference can be explained by the nature of the real data vs. the benchmarking data. It is 20 x 2048 x 2048 and has about 1.7 million objects to label, 80% of which are of size 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt. My idea is to apply the row-by-row connected components algorithm. The idea is that rather than trying to flood-fill to identify all members of a component, you start labelling at each row, and note each time you arrive at a contradiction.

Afterwards, you take your list of contradictions, and merge them into the same class.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMIrQdX4BkE) explains the algorithm.

This has the disadvantage that it takes two passes over the input data. However, it has the advantage that it has really good cache coherency. In other words, it accesses all of the data in the array in order.

This is the same algorithm that `scipy.ndimage.label()` is following internally, but we can be faster than that, because we don't need to call it once for each class.

Here's the code I used.

```
@numba.njit
def adjacent(idx, shape):
    coords = []
    if len(shape) > 2:
        if idx[0] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0] - 1, idx[1], idx[2]))
        if idx[1] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0], idx[1] - 1, idx[2]))
        if idx[2] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0], idx[1], idx[2] - 1))
    else:
        if idx[0] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0] - 1, idx[1]))
        if idx[1] > 0:
            coords.append((idx[0], idx[1] - 1))
    return coords


@numba.njit
def merge_classes(labels, mergetable):
    for idx in np.ndindex(labels.shape):
        class_num = labels[idx]
        if class_num < len(mergetable):
            merge_target = mergetable[class_num]
            if merge_target != -1:
                labels[idx] = merge_target


@numba.njit
def add_to_merge_table(mergetable, class1, class2):
    # identify smallest element
    lo_class = min(class1, class2)
    hi_class = max(class1, class2)
    # Does the merge table require expansion?
    while len(mergetable) <= hi_class:
        new_mergetable = np.zeros(len(mergetable) * 2, dtype=np.int32)
        new_mergetable[:] = -1
        new_mergetable[:len(mergetable)] = mergetable
        mergetable = new_mergetable
    while mergetable[lo_class] != -1:
        lo_class = mergetable[lo_class]
    mergetable[hi_class] = lo_class
    return mergetable
                    

@numba.njit
def label_image(decoded_image):
    labels = np.zeros_like(decoded_image, dtype=np.uint32)
    current_label = 0
    mergetable = np.zeros(8, dtype=np.int32)
    mergetable[:] = -1
    for idx in np.ndindex(labels.shape):
        decoded_image_idx = decoded_image[idx]
        labels_idx = labels[idx]
        for aidx in adjacent(idx, labels.shape):
            labels_aidx = labels[aidx]
            if labels_aidx != 0 and decoded_image[aidx] == decoded_image_idx:
                # Already have class for neighboring pixel
                if labels_idx == 0:
                    # This pixel has no class, copy neighbor
                    labels_idx = labels[idx] = labels_aidx
                elif labels_aidx != labels_idx:
                    # This pixel has a contradictory class
                    # Assign minimum and add to merge table
                    mergetable = add_to_merge_table(mergetable, labels_aidx, labels_idx)
                    labels_idx = labels[idx] = min(labels_idx, labels_aidx)
        if labels_idx == 0:
            current_label += 1
            labels[idx] = current_label
    merge_classes(labels, mergetable)
    return labels, current_label
```

It is roughly 30% faster than the iterative version on the random array I tried.

Comment: I've optimized the iterative approach now. Could you rerun your benchmark?